# How to Add additional text in ListView except event.title?

Tags: vue.js, fullcalendar

I used ListView, Now ListView show only event.title. But I want to add additional string from extendedProps.

I've try to use eventRender prop like this,

```
eventRender (info) {
  if (info.view.constructor.name === 'ListView') {
    var title = info.el.getElementsByClassName('fc-list-item-title')[0]
    if (title) {
      title.innerHTML = `${info.event.title} ${info.event.extendedProps.mobile}
      <br>${info.event.extendedProps.description}`
    }
  }
},
```

It work only when I `yarn serve`
But when vue build with `yarn build`. It not work.

Comment: Define "not work". Do you get an error message of some sort? It's unclear why this specific bit of code would depend on yarn...it seems to be client side code only with no dependency outside  fullCalendar. Please clarify the circumstances

Comment: @ADyson When yarn build `info.view.constructor.name -> "ListView" ` it change to `n`.

Answer (score 1):

I found solution.

change

```
if (info.view.constructor.name === 'ListView') {}
```

to

```
const isList = info.view.type.includes('list')
if (isList) {}
```